# MariaDB/MySQL table encryption Without restart

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb

I had the success to setup MariaDb 10.1.14 encryption Data at rest by following the steps from [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/encryption-key-management/) article. But I would have to restart the server to get that working. I wanted to get the encryption working without restart. So I did the following steps:

- Install MariaDb
- Made sure service is running

Make the ini changes required for ecryption

```
plugin_load_add = file_key_management

file_key_management_filename = C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\data\myKey.enc

file_key_management_filekey = FILE:<UserProfileFolder>\myPwd.key

file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = aes_cbc

innodb_encrypt_tables = ON

innodb_encrypt_log = ON

innodb_tablespaces_encryption = ON

innodb_encryption_threads = 4
```

Ran the sql to activate the encryption plugin

```
install plugin FILE_KEY_MANAGEMENT soname 'file_key_management';

SET GLOBAL innodb_encrypt_tables=ON;

SET GLOBAL innodb_encryption_threads=4;
```

- After setting all this the encryption didn't started
- I found that I would have to manually run the alter table statement to enable encryption on all the existing tables and I don't know how can do that for Redologs and Tablespaces also without restart, but **I don't have to do this if I restart the service**.

I would really appreciate if any guidance is provided on this.

Comment: Although I have the gut feeling that you do not want to hear that: you need to restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, but I did found something that did triggered the encryption for the tables without restarting. 
When I run the queries to activate the encryption plugin added one more query to it

`SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.innodb_tablespaces_encryption where ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = 1;`

And this query does the magic. So it seems like once the encryption plugin is activated, need to check the information_schema.innodb_tablespaces_encryption and that would make the plugin into action.

But still there is a caveat that it doesn't encrypt the Logs as innodb_encrypt_log global variable is readonly.